# bash - For each directory in a folder, make a directory within a different location

Tags: bash

I have a directory which contains several folders.
I'd like to make a bash script to create directories with the same name in a different location.

Note that I don't want to copy the folder structure, neither copy or move the folders. I just want to create folders with the same name in a different location.

I'm stuck. Using this:

```
for d in "template/modules/*"
do
    # mkdir $(basename "$d");
    echo $d;
    echo "$d";
    echo $(basename "$d");
done
```

Output:

```
template/modules/introduction template/modules/kitchen template/modules/test
template/modules/*
add_module.sh template
```

Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: `*` in double quote won't be expanded. Try `"template/modules/"*` instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to put the asterisk outside the quotes:

```
for d in "template/modules/"*
```

In the first `echo`, `$d` is [expanded](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob), but when you quote it, it's not.

Comment: You might want to upvote @XièJìléi's comment as well; it was posted before my reply :)

Answer (score 3):

To copy the directory structure, you can do this:

```
$ cd template/modules
$ find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec mkdir -p ../../{} \;
```

Comment: I don't really need to copy the whole folder structure. I just need to create the same folders as the modules/ directory in the current directory...

Comment: Use `-maxdepth 1` in your find command. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
for d in "template/modules/*"
do
   mkdir $(basename "$d")
done
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It creates a folder called 'basename template' and within it a folder named 'modules' and within that a folder named '.'

Comment: @RafaelGP see the updated version, you must confused the ` with `'`